# Angular 1.2 to 1.3 - Link Generation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here are two simple apps using ui-router in angular 1.2 and 1.3:

1.2 - http://jsbin.com/niyehagixa/1/edit?html,output

1.3 - http://jsbin.com/vaceqizanu/1/edit?html,output

If you inspect the link for "State a" in the first, it appears as: `href="#/a"`; however, in the angular 1.3 version it is now being set as `href="/a"`, missing the `#`.

Can anyone explain why this is?  In my existing application (attempting to upgrade to 1.3), most of the links without the `#` still get routed correctly; however, some are attempting to go to the server which  will return a 404 (this would also be true if a user attempted to copy the link or open it in a new tab/window).

I'd rather not add any complexity on the server side maintaining what urls should go to the SPA:  Is there a way for me to keep the `#` in the links in 1.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1483

Comment: Looks like v0.2.12 is still being worked on; I'll hold off until that's ready to go.  Thanks!

Comment: 0.2.12-pre1 was tagged in the meantime to support angular 1.3

Comment: If I am not using `ui-router` and am experiencing the same problem do I need it? I have `angular.js`, `angular-resource.js`, and `angular-route.js` in my project (along with some other js packages like `bootstrap` and `ui-bootstrap-tpls`). When I went from 1.2 to 1.3 all my deep links broke and are falling through to the `$routeProvider.otherwise` statement. I don't know where to start looking.